# PHP / MySQL practice

Tags: php, mysql

What would a potential employer think when seeing a function such as:

```
function updTable{$table, $primary, $id, $key, $value){
    $primary = mysql_real_escape_string($primary);
    $id = (int) $id;
    $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $table = mysql_real_escape_string($table);

    mysql_query("UPDATE `{$table}` SET
                `{$key}`=`{$value}` 
                WHERE `{$primary}` = {$id}");

}
```

Is this bad practice?  Are there any good articles on general php / mysql design guidelines (not syntax) I should read and know about?

Comment: The escaping is good, although it won't run - function parameters need to be enclosed in round brackets, not braces. The PHP community has begun the deprecation process for mysql functions however, use PDO MySQL or mysqli instead. I tend to advise people to consider ORMs too, though the learning curve is a bit steep for beginners - Propel and Doctrine come to mind.

Comment: Yes its bad practice, firstly the mysql_* functions are in the deprecation process and only 1 field can be updated at once making it inefficient, tho a class based CRUD/DAO using PDO is another story

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, based on the answer and your comments, I will dedicate some time to get to know PDO, Doctorine, and prepared statements to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are handling your database interaction is from yesteryear.  [Prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) are the norm now and thwart a lot of SQL related attacks.

Also, depending on your system design, you would never have a need for a function like this.  If you were using an MVC pattern, you'd write a method in your model that would handle a certain type of update instead of just a generic table update.

Looking at this function, what happens if you want to update multiple columns in that table?  If, for example, you are updating 3 columns, you would have to make a call to your database 3 times, instead of one time.

If you want something that could be a very general database layer, take a look at [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/index.html) or make something very similar to it.

Comment: Insightful response, thank you.  I haven't touched php/mysql programming in over two years and will definetly look at your resources provided.